# is it possible to upload fixed file from fixed pc path by php? (ex: "C:\uploadfile.zip")

Tags: php, upload

i want to upload fixed file from fixed pc path without use input. (ex: "C:\uploadfile.zip")

i tried this but not working.

```
$myfile= "C:\uploadfile.zip";
$uploaddir = "files/";
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES["$myfile"]['name']);
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$myfile"]['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n"; }
```

is it possible to upload fixed file from fixed pc path?

Comment: You can use `copy` (http://fr2.php.net/copy) for this

Comment: <?php
$file = 'c:\uploadfile.zip';
$newfile = "files/newfile.zip";

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";

} else {
echo "copied ok";
}
?>

Comment: Warning: copy(c:\uploadfile.zip): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/host/public_html/test/copy.php on line 15
failed to copy c:\uploadfile.zip

Comment: if try copy in localhost.. its working fine but if try to copy from my pc to remote server got error message

Comment: Remote server is on the web, Local server is on my computer.